# Capture reflecting image

Tags: optics, reflection

Suppose you have following installation:

```
    +-------------------+
    | O               M |
    +-------+   +-------+
            |   |
            | C |
            +---+
```

View from top. In a corridor object $O$ gets reflected by a mirror wall $M$. Is it theoretically or practically possible to capture any information about the object using camera $C$?

Answer (score 4):

Unless the walls are perfectly non-reflective, light can take a path like

[image: diffuse light path]

It doesn't matter if the reflection off the walls is [highly diffuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection).  There will be a hue change so at least *some* information about the object can be captured.  For a diffuse reflection you get something like:

[image: diffuse reflection]

Just imagine the walls are very clean and a very bright white.  If the object is a highly saturated color you could easily see the color change on the walls via a diffuse reflection.  It will look like a colorful glow coming from around the corner.  The mirror will help reduce the places light can get absorbed so it will have a small helpful effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My wild guess was more like this:

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It validates my expectations. My further (wild) speculation was more like this: if someone is observing O standing behind it, this person will be able to see the reflection of the object in the mirror on the opposite side of the corridor. This means information is being transferred across to the mirror and back. A "camera" positioned in the side corridor should be able to notice a difference "in the ether" when mirror is and isn't there. If O would be shooting pingpong balls to the mirror and some will be bouncing back, camera should be able to see them.